# BeautifulSoup: Get all product links from specific category

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the product links from specific category by using BeautifulSoup in Python.

I have tried the following but don't get a result:

```
import lxml
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/category/bedding/bedding/quilts-coverlets/12018/1-96?pagSortOpt=DEFAULT-0&view=grid")

br= BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'lxml')

for links in br.findAll('a', class_='prodImg'):
    print links['href']
```

Comment: did you check what you get in html?

Comment: i got nothing on the output screen.

Comment: please try to run the code

Answer (score 1):

You use urllib2 wrong.

```
import lxml
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#create a http request
req=urllib2.Request("http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/category/bedding/bedding/quilts-coverlets/12018/1-96?pagSortOpt=DEFAULT-0&view=grid")
# send the request
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
# read the content of the response
html = response.read()
br= BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

for links in br.findAll('a', class_='prodImg'):
    print links['href']
```

Comment: What do you get in response

Comment: @Vishal should be ok now

Comment: actually, in the "inspect element" all the product link are showing within <li> tag but when i use "br.prettify" to displaying all the html element, then no any product link is displaying.

Comment: @Vishal if the code already works as it is and `br.prettify` is the problem, then dont do it! Or please make an effort to explain what is the result you are looking for.

Comment: There are 96 products in the given url and i just want to get all the product links.

Comment: @Vishal with this code, I get exactly 96 links, so please be more specific about what you want...

Comment: but, i don't get any output. My output screen just goes blank.any suggestion that i have made any mistake ??

Comment: @Vishal what are you using? How do you launch your script?

Comment: @Whitefret have u used any other libraries ??

Comment: i am using python GUI on windows 10

Comment: I just copy past the code to Ipython on Linux.
you get nothing when you print br?

Comment: @Vishal anyway, this code works, if you want me to help you debug you need to give me some information like what error message do you get, what you get when you print different object (like html, br...). With your "It doesn't work", I can't really do anything

Comment: using "br", i get all the element which are above the product link not below that.

Comment: i am sorry ,am not allowed to post lakhs of lines . but i am posting last few lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html=requests.get("http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/category/bedding/bedding/quilts-coverlets/12018/1-96?pagSortOpt=DEFAULT-0&view=grid")

br= BeautifulSoup(html.content,"lxml")

data=br.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'productShadow'})
for div in br.find_all('a'):
        print div.get('href')
```

try this code